# Clean Url from empty parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

how can I remove empty paramaters from Url:

```
http://localhost:12058/User/Doctors?pageNumber=1&HospitalId=&DepartmentId=&specialityId=&name=&email=
```

In my case I want clean Url from: `name=&email=`

I try do this:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "User", name = UrlParameter.Optional, email = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

but it is not work for me

Comment: I want to have url without empty parameters

Comment: If the suggestion below solved your problem, please mark the question as solved by clicking the tickbox to the left of the answer.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you want: what have you *tried*?

Comment: I try the code I wrote in my question (routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "User", name = UrlParameter.Optional, email = UrlParameter.Optional });
) in Global.asax